# bringing a windows form, form to the front without minimising other windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm relatively new to C# and completely new to windows form and basically trying to create a subliminal messaging program that at timed intervals will quickly display a message for it to then be hidden again.

I've managed to by looking through various other posts created another form that will pop up and then hide very quickly using

```
msgObject.Activate();
```

that brings the form to the front. However it is stopping me from being able to type when I'm working and I basically wanting to know if it is possible to make some kind of message or form appear at the front of all my other programs without it interrupting my current work or opening or closing of other windows and tasks if that makes sense. As currently it brings the form to the front of everything but will also stop me from being able to type etc.

I'm not sure if this is possible with my current method of using a form but if there is a way of achieving the result I'm after I'd be very grateful to find out

Thanks.

Here is more of my code to clarify

```
 public partial class FormHomePage : Form
{
    private bool startSubliminal = false;
    msg msgObject = new msg();

    List<string> subliminalMessages = new List<string>();
    public FormHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (startSubliminal)
        {
            msgObject.Show();
            msgObject.BringToFront();
            msgObject.Activate();
        }

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        subliminalMessages.Add(txtBox1.Text);
        msgObject.LabelText = txtBox1.Text;
        txtBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        startSubliminal = true;
        msgObject.Show();
        msgObject.BringToFront();

    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msgObject.Hide();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that displaying a window is hardly going to be "subliminal". Between the animation of displaying the window, its going to look like some strange window/control spontaneously popping up and closing. Not really "subliminal", would likely just appear as an odd error occurring.

Comment: `Activate` doesn't minimize other windows. Is the problem that your window is taking keyboard focus away from whichever other window you had been working in? If so, `Activate` is not the way to do what you want, because its whole purpose *is* to take focus. ("Activates the form and gives it focus." - [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)) I'm not sure if they'll do what you want but you could try `Show` or `BringToFront` instead.

Comment: Activate is the only thing that appears to be bringing my form to the front and it might not intentionally minimise other windows but it does say if I launch a full screen program such as a game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you showing the second form (the message form) in the first place? You're probably using `.Show()` *(right?)*, which will make the form "steal" the focus anyway. The same applies to `.Activate()` and `.BringToFront()`.

Instead, what you can do is to show the message form *and make sure it stays on top the current form*, and then activate the current/main form once again.

Something like this should work:

```
var frm = new YourMsgForm();
frm.Show(this);
this.Activate();
```

Here's a demonstration:

[image: Showing a secondary form without interrupting the current one.]

Note that I used `.Show(this)` instead of `.Show()`, that's in order to set the current form as the *[Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner)* of the new one, that way we guarantee that the new form will stay on top of the current one. This is equivalent to calling `frm.Owner = this;` then `frm.Show();`.

Another way to make sure the form stays on top is by setting the [`TopMost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.topmost) property instead of the `Owner` property. However, doing so will make the new form on top of the other windows as well (not just your application).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I added more of my main forms code below my original post as I tried the this suggestion but it didnt bring the form to the front of all my other programs I had running so it didn't work for me

Comment: I didn't fully understand it sorry I re read it again now and the topmost fixed it thanks!

Now I'm going to look into to see if its still possible to click under the form that pops up. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't know why not but since I've been adding new features and tested having the subliminal message appear for longer during some tests I've noticed each time the message appears it takes me of what I'm working on or unhighlights what I've highlighted for example which is interrupting work that I am doing which defeats the point of the program. I'm still using:

   subliminalMessageForm.Show();
     subliminalMessageForm.TopMost = true;